# How to find the song filename when using media library

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I get song title from media library using

```
private void ListSongs()
    {
       MediaLibrary lib = new MediaLibrary();
       var SongName = (from m in lib.Songs
       select m.Name).ToList();
       listBox1.ItemsSource = SongName;
}
```

Here I can get song title as m.name, how do i get filename? It might be that the filename is different than the song title.

Comment: I looked through the documentation (as I'm sure you have also) and it doesn't look like they make the filename available from the Song class (or anywhere else in the MediaLibary either.)

Comment: yes i also did not find, Is there any other way to get the filename?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get the filename of Songs from MediaLibrary, you also cannot access the file Stream of these files. Access to Songs in MediaLibrary is basically sandboxed to prevent applications from "deleting" or "stealing" your music.